# add function to namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I've defined the following JS constructor function

```
function FV.Map(element) {
  // impl omitted
}
```

The function definition causes the following error to appear in Firebug

> missing ( before formal parameters

The FV is a global object that I use as a namespace for all my functions. Apparently this is not the right way to add this function to this namespace, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.FV = window.FV || {}
FV.Map = function(element) {
    //…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more intuitive syntax would perhaps be this...

```
window.FV = {
    Map: function(element){
       Do Something
    },
    Morefuncs: function(element, element2){
       Do something else
    }
};
```